# logstash-forwarder json invalid character

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-forwarder

At some point my logstash forwarder used to work properly but at some point fail to start with this error message

> Failed unmarshalling json: invalid character ']' looking for beginning of value logstash

This message appears only if i run forwarder with this command:

```
$ /opt/logstash-forwarder/bin/logstash-forwarder -config="/etc/logstash-forwarder"
```

If i run it as a service it fails without any error message, if i restart the service getting this

> Restarting log shipper logstash-forwarder
>   start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill PID: No such process
>   ...done.

The first time stopped forwarder working i found in syslog this message:

> connection from UDP: [54.194.184.218]:63707->[10.38.143.181] Nov 21
>   12:41:38 logstash-forwarder[PID]: 2014/11/21 12:41:38.692517 Read
>   error looking for ack: EOF Nov 21 12:41:38 logstash-forwarder[PID]:
>   2014/11/21 12:41:38.692592 Setting trusted CA from file:
>   /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt Nov 21 12:41:38
>   logstash-forwarder[PID]: 2014/11/21 12:41:38.692827 Connecting to
>   X.X.X.X:5000 (X.X.X.X) Nov 21 12:41:38 logstash-forwarder[PID]:
>   2014/11/21 12:41:38.694128 Failure connecting to X.X.X.X: dial tcp
>   X.X.X.X:5000: connection refused

At server side `logstash` and ES cluster seems to work fine..

I found many similar problems with mine but not any solution.

Comment: Sounds like you have bad JSON data in the configuration file(s).

Comment: but it worked for days.

Comment: Thanks magnus you where right after further inspection problem fixed.